# How to access my config file laravel 5?

Tags: file, config, laravel-5.1

I created a config file in the folder : "App/Config" called "blog.php"

```
<?php return ['name' => 'Admin'];
```

How can i access to this file and to the name value ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your `config` file at `ConfigServiceProvider` then you will be able to access your config variable like `Config::get('filename.varname');`

See this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/ho-to-access-config-variables-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0):

just call it directly `Config::get('blog.name')`

blog as the filename

name as the array key